# ViewFlipper with long texts

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, viewflipper, android-animation

I would like to create a ViewFlipper with translate animation to flip between TextViews with long text (like a running line). Problem is the text gets either wrapped into more than one line or cut off if i use 'android:singleLine'. How can overcome this problem?

Comment: plz explain what u want to do in more details.The question is not descriptive

Comment: Hi, i added a better description of what I want to achieve under Khawar's reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using ViewFlipper for this? May be your question is not that clear. Anyways here are some suggestions, for running a Long Text Line, you can use textview:ellipsize = "marquee" while singleLine = true or maxLines = 1.

Secondly if you want to control the scrolling you can use Horizontal scrollView with your long TextView in it having maxLines = 1.

Comment: The reason I am using a ViewFlipper is that I want to flip between several TextViews, each containing a long text. The number of texts is not constant, so I really prefer using a ViewFlipper instead of just building each time one huge text view (with all texts) and giving it ellipsize with marquee. So basically I just need a way to prevent the long text from being cropped. Can you think of anything I can do to make it happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: p.s. texts = text string i want placed inside each TextView.